# Setting API level in Android Studio backend

Tags: android, backend

I have an android project in two parts in Android Studio.  In the android app i can set the "minSdkVersion" in build.gradle.  However, I cannot find a similar setting in the backend build.gradle.  I am getting a series of warning saying a feature requires a minimum sdk.  It isnt critical, but it is distracting.  Thanks

Maybe a better question to ask is how do you set the SDK in a non-android project?

Comment: What is backend build.gradle?

Comment: perhaps I am not using standard terminology.  Android Studio allows you to build a webapp and either deploy it to their cloud services App Engine (GAE) or run it locally as a test server.  https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/endpoints/add_module So the backend build.gradle is the build file associated with the backend module.  Studio is throwing a bunch of warnings in my webapp files telling me I am not using the correct SDK, which is annoying (and a considerable time sink) but doesnt affect the actual deployment.

Comment: Did you get any news on how to solve that? thks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mention 'minSdkVersion' in project's build.gradle file as it will be only app module's build.gradle file. Top level build.gradle file is used to mention settings which will be common in all modules of your application.

Comment: I see 3 build.gradle files, one for the app, one for the backend, one for the libraries.   I don't understand your reference to a 'top level' gradle file.  Also,  'minSdkVersion' appears to only go in an android tag.  Maybe a better question to ask is how do you set the SDK in a non-android project?